# C programming - freopen append a ? to the filename

Tags: c, filenames, stdout, io-redirection, freopen

I am writing a c program that simulates the linux shell.

In order to implement i/o redirection using redirection symbol i.e. the > symbol, i make use of freopen to replace stdout with file specified by the user.
If say the command is:

```
environ > bla.txt
```

My shell will print out the environment variables into bla.txt file instead of stdout.

However, instead of creating "bla.txt" file, the file created is "bla.txt?".

Can anyone solve the mystery behind the ? appended to the filename?

Here's the code for the i/o redirection only:

```
 char *inFile;   

pid_t pid;      
int rc;        

/* keep reading input until "quit" command or eof of redirected input */
while (!feof(stdin)) 
{
    /* get command line from input */
    if (fgets (buf, MAX_BUFFER, stdin ))    // read a line
    { 

        inFile = strstr(buf, ">");          // look for redirection arrow > in the command
        if(inFile != NULL)                 
        {
            pid = fork();

            if(pid == 0)                            
                freopen( inFile+2, "w", stdout);    
            else if(pid == -1)      
                syserr("fork");     
            else
                waitpid(pid,&rc,0);        
        }
     }
}
```

I have tried googling the solution but can't find anything.
I have also tried looking at other stackoverflow question, but can't find answer.

Thanks.

Comment: As (essentially) always, `while (!feof(whatever))` is broken. You want: `while (fgets(...))`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the `fgets` man page:

> `fgets()`  reads  in  at most one less than size characters from stream and stores them into the buffer pointed to by s.  Reading stops after an EOF or a newline.  **If a newline is read, it is  stored  into the buffer.** [...]

You need to strip the end-of-line marker from the string, otherwise you'll end up with a filename that contains it (and most shells/implementations of `ls` will replace that with a `?` by default).

Comment: ah i see. That explains why when i type in "dir" into the terminal, the filename is appended with \n. I tried to find the \n using strcmp, but it doesn't return 0??

Comment: `strcmp` isn't something you use to find things in strings. You've shown you already know `strstr` which could be used for that. Or `strchr` if you only care about Unix-type line endings.

Comment: ^ solve it by stripping the newline character. I created my own method of deleting unwanted character from a string. Thanks mat :)

Answer (score 0):

write a piece of code in c language  which solves my below mentioned purpose------

let  i have a folder named wild consisting 
 5 files--
 cat,dog,horse,lion,tiger

now using c/java(file handling concept) write a code to rename those file as---

animal cat,animal dog,animal horse,animal lion,animal tiger